# How do you put multiple default scopes on on a model?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, model, default-scope

I was wondering how do you have multiple default scopes (ordering) on a model for example I have a comments model that needs ordering by both date and approved:

```
default_scope :order => 'approved ASC', :order => 'date ASC'
```

So how do you have both of these ordering put on a model, so I first orders by approved, and then by date.

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the good syntax for ordering with several fields :

```
default_scope :order => 'approved ASC, date ASC'
```

Answer (score 8):

In Rails 4+ you can do:

```
default_scope -> { order(approved: :asc, date: :asc) }
```